# When I am trying to run setup:upgrade its always gives below error,

Tags: magento2, php, database

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE 446 WHERE `Non_unique` = 1' at line 1, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM 434 WHERE 'Non_unique'=1
```

due to above error I am unable to install any modules.
Please help someone at the earliest how to resolve this?

Comment: is it in core or you custom module?

Comment: Its in core not in custom module @AbdulSamadAbbasi

Answer (score 0):

Just run composer update once and then try with the setup:upgrade command

Comment: No luck still the same error